Sequelize syntax error at or near "ON DELETE" when using associations
I've created a simple express app with a Postgres database using Sequelize as the ORM to define my models.
I have two models where there is a one-to-many relationship:

A Faction can have many Craters
A Crater belongs to one Faction

These associations are defined as a method on each model class.
The models are exported as modules and added to a db object, which is exported as a Sequelize instance in models/index.js; the exact same way sequelize-cli creates model templates:
models/Faction.js:
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class pgFaction extends Model {
    // helper methods here
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.hasMany(models.Crater, { 
        foreignKey: 'faction',
        sourceKey: 'name'
      });
    }
  };
  pgFaction.init( 
  {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('Klamp', 'Laz', 'Pirates', 'Police'),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        notNull: { msg: 'Faction must have a Name.' },
        notEmpty: { msg: 'Faction Name must not be empty.' },
      },
    },
    enemy: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('Klamp', 'Laz', 'Pirates', 'Police'),
      allowNull: true
    },
    friend: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('Klamp', 'Laz', 'Pirates', 'Police'),
      allowNull: true
    }
  },
  {
    sequelize, modelName: 'Faction'
  });
  return pgFaction;
};

Factions are deterministic, unique and there are a finite number created, so the Faction name can be the primary key.
models/Crater.js:
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class pgCrater extends Model {
    // helper methods here
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(models.Faction, {
        foreignKey: 'faction',
        targetKey: 'name'
        });
    }
  };
pgCrater.init(
  {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('Alpha','Downtown', 'Gamma'),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        notNull: { msg: 'Crater must have a Name.' },
        notEmpty: { msg: 'Crater Name must not be empty.' },
      },
    },
    // does the foreign key 'faction' need to be defined or can it be referenced from the parent table via the association?
    faction: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('Klamp', 'Laz', 'Pirates', 'Police'),
    },
    hasMonorail: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
      validate: {
        notNull: { msg: 'hasMonorail must be either true or false.' },
        notEmpty: { msg: 'hasMonorail must not be empty.' },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize, modelName: 'Crater'
  });
  return pgCrater;
};

The same goes for the Craters - finite, unique and pre-determined so name can be the primary key.
When I start my app from server.js, the sequelize instance from models/index.js (with instantiated models) is imported.  It then connects to the database before attempting to start the app:
server.js:
const { sequelize } = require('./src/api/models/postgres/index');
const pgStoreProc = require('./config/db/storeproc-postgres');
...
...
async function main() {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Postgres connection via Sequelize has been established successfully.');
      return true;
    });
    await sequelize.sync({force: true})
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Synced Postgres tables.");
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("An error occurred updating the Postgres tables.");
    })
    .then(() => {
      app.listen(port, () => {
...
...
finally {
  pgStoreProc.testFactionCrater();
}
main();

Upon starting the app (for now), I drop all my tables in the database with the .sync({force: true}) and re-create them using a custom stored procedure (I am not using migrations and do not have a migrations directory) simplified here as an example:
storeproc-postgres:
const { sequelize } = require('../../src/api/models/postgres');
const pgFaction = sequelize.models.Faction;
const pgCrater = sequelize.models.Crater;

let testFactionCrater = async function () {
    console.log("\nCreating faction ...");
    await pgFaction.create(
        {"name": "Laz", "friend": "", "enemy": "Klamp"}
    );
    console.log("\nCreating crater ...");
    await pgCrater.create(
        {"name": "Alpha", "faction": "Laz", "connectingCraters": ["Downtown"], "hasMonorail": true}
    );
}

When I run the app with npm, I can see the existing tables being dropped and then an attempt to re-create them.  However, the Craters table does not get created because of an SQL syntax error.
The first error I receive is:
original: error: relation "Craters" does not exist because the preceding SQL query to CREATE the Craters table hasn't worked, so the INSERT fails.
So, I inserted a .sync() to create each table before inserting the model entry (with the .create() method), which shows the syntax error of the SQL query to CREATE the Craters table:
Error
    at Query.run (/home/jimjamz/dev/misop/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:50:25)
    at /home/jimjamz/dev/misop/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:315:28
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async PostgresQueryInterface.createTable (/home/jimjamz/dev/misop/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:98:12)
    at async Crater.sync (/home/jimjamz/dev/misop/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:942:7)
    at async Object.testFactionCrater (/home/jimjamz/dev/misop/config/db/storeproc-postgres.js:15:5) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: error: syntax error at or near "ON"
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/jimjamz/dev/misop/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:283:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/home/jimjamz/dev/misop/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:122:29)
      at Parser.parse (/home/jimjamz/dev/misop/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:35:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/jimjamz/dev/misop/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
      at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:191:23) {
    length: 92,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '42601',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: '135',
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'scan.l',
    line: '1176',
    routine: 'scanner_yyerror',
    sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Craters" ("name" "public"."enum_Craters_name" NOT NULL UNIQUE , "faction" "public"."enum_Craters_faction" ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE, "connectingCraters" VARCHAR(255)[] DEFAULT ARRAY[]::VARCHAR(255)[], "hasMonorail" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("name"));',
    parameters: undefined
  }

I can see from the above SQL query that ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE is the issue.  If I remove this from the query and run it manually, it creates the Craters table.
Alternatively, if I simply comment out the associations in the two models, the tables are also created successfully and the data is inserted.
What is the problem, and what am I doing wrong?
